# Grade is calculated incorrectly

Tags: python

The code bellow seems to be semantically functional only for the first student, as his grade is calculated correctly. For the second student it does not calculate the expected grade . Another  problem is how to print the iterator from the for loop so that I get the prompt:

> Enter name of assessment 1:
>
> Enter name of assessment 2:
>
> etc...

```
assessment=[]
weight=[]
assign_number = int(input('How many assessment : '))
def main():
    for i in range(assign_number):
        asses_name =input('Enter name of assessment: ')
        assessment.append(asses_name)
        asses_value =int(input('How many marks is the ' + assessment[i] + ' worth : '))
        weight.append(asses_value)

    if sum(weight)!= 100:
        del weight[:]
        print("the total is not 100, please re enter")
        main()
    else:
        student_details()

def calculatedgrade(score):
    if 100<= score:
        grade = 'High Distiction'
    elif 80 <= score <= 100:
        grade = 'High Distiction'
    elif 70 <= score <= 79:
        grade = 'Distiction'
    elif 60 <= score<= 69:
        grade ='Credit'
    elif 50 <= score <= 59:
        grade = 'Pass'
    elif score <=50:
        grade = 'Fail'
    return grade

def student_details():

    student_name =[]
    student_mark =[]
    marks=[]
    total_mark=[]
    student_number = int(input('How many students : '))

    for n in range(student_number):
        name = input('What is the name of student: ')
        student_name.append(name)

        for m in range(assign_number):
            mark = input('what did ' + format(student_name[n])+' get out of 
' +format(weight[m]) +' in the ' +assessment[m] +' ?')
            marks.append(mark)
            score = int(marks[m])/int(weight[m])*100
            student_mark.append(score)
            calculatedgrade(score)
            print(mark,' out of ',weight[m],'is a ',(calculatedgrade(score))

main ()
```

Comment: How does `main` get called?

Comment: For name of assessment , you can use the below code:

for i in range(assign_number): 
    display = 'Enter name of assessment ' + str(i+1) + ': ' 
    asses_name =input(display)

Answer (score 0):

For printing the counter: print your current display string concatenated to **i**. Like so:

```
stringForInput = 'Enter name of assessment ' 
for i in range(assign_number):
         stringForInput =  stringForInput + str(i+1) + ' :'
         asses_name =input(stringForInput)
```

Comment: @Jessica you should edit you code so we see where is the main() called